# How to size content for presentation detents in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I can display a sheet with a custom height with detents in SwiftUI like this.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
    MySheet()
        presentationDetents([.height(500), .large])
}
```

Is there a way that I can measure the exact height of my view `MySheet` and pass this to `presentationDetents` without having a fixed value? I ask because based on the user's accessibility settings the height of the view could change.

Comment: Did you try `GeometryReader` on MySheet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Approach:

- Measure the size of the content being presented and set the value into a @State variable
- Use `GeometryReader` in the background of the content being presented to measure the height of content.
- `GeometryReader` is added to the background of the content being presented and not to the foreground because `GeometryReader` tends to expand to all the space given to it like color or shape.

## Note:

- This is one crude way to do it, happy to hear any better approaches
- For multiline text please add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to the text

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSheetShown = false
    @State private var sheetContentHeight = CGFloat(0)

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet") {
            isSheetShown = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShown) {
            VStack {
                Text("hello line 1")
                Text("hello line 2")
                Text("hello line 3")
            }
            .background {
                //This is done in the background otherwise GeometryReader tends to expand to all the space given to it like color or shape.
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .task {
                            print("size = \(proxy.size.height)")
                            sheetContentHeight = proxy.size.height
                        }
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(sheetContentHeight)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the text is multiline, it won't return you correct value for the height.

Comment: For multiline text add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to the `Text` so that it can grow vertically

Comment: @user1046037 you're my friggin hero. The `.fixedSize(...)` was giving me a headache for a while now. I've just been arbitrarily adding in a 80 height to offset the multilines xD

Comment: when switching colorScheme or moving to another app then going back, it make the view totally breaks